# Open a SAS dataframe in R with Hmisc

Tags: r, sas

I'd like to open a SAS dataframe .sas7dbat in R.

I find a package for that : [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/Hmisc.pdf) (p 237), but I don't understand the syntax.

For now, when I want to import the dataset *data* which is in the librabry *lib* I do that :

**EDIT :**

> test<-sas.get(libraryName="C:/Users/.../lib"
>                         , member="data")

A SAS log windows appeared, but I have this error message

```
Error in sas.get(libraryName = "C:/Users/.../lib",  : 
  SAS job failed with status 127
In addition: Warning message:
In sas.get(libraryName = "C:/Users/.../lib",  :
  C:/Users/.../lib/formats.sc? or formats.sas7bcat  not found. Formatting ignored.
```

I think the syntax is false, but I don't understand the example of the documentation.

ps : I have SAS 9.3 in my computer

Comment: try putting lib in quotes i.e. "lib"

Comment: Can you make a copy of your code that fills out the arguments as much as possible, give it a go and post it in your post to make it easier to check please? It should look along the lines of `test<-sas.get(libraryName="C:/.../library/lib/", member="data.sas7bdat")` based on the documentation.

Comment: the 127 message is somewhat helpful, there's a nabble post where someone had the same issue and it came down to needing paths to be explicitly stated... http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/SAS-Import-with-sas-get-Hmisc-status-127-error-td4513896.html

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I never managed to get `sas.get` working. In any case, all it does is write your dataset to a text file, and then call `read.table` on it. Since you still need to have SAS, you can just as easily run `PROC EXPORT` and write the text file yourself.